# Sending Control Commands to UIWebView for Online Game - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, xcode6

I am trying to port a basic game to iOS that is only playable on the web. However, the web version is unplayable for iDevices because of the lack of proper keyboard controls, despite the fact that it runs perfectly speed wise. Is there any way to emulate a keyboard and pass a, say (W) key or (Space) bar from a UIButton to a UIWebView, and produce the desired effect? Is such a thing even possible in swift?

P.S. I already have the web view set up and functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` and pass the appropriate javascript to emulate the key press.

For the javascript see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187302/427083).

Comment: This looks promising! How would I evaluate this in swift, or begin doing so by passing javascript (excuse my lack of javascript knowledge)?